# Unable to uninstall an older CUDAResource paclet

Tags: packages, cudalink, gpu, paclets, cuda

I am trying to uninstall an older version of CUDAResource but cannot do so. Any ideas please? Is there a manual way to do so?

```
CUDAResourcesUninstall[]

PacletUninstall::nodelete: The paclet named CUDALink at location E:\Mathematica 12.1\SystemFiles\Links\CUDALink cannot be uninstalled because it does not reside in the standard paclet repository.

PacletUninstall::nodelete: The paclet named GPUTools at location E:\Mathematica 12.1\SystemFiles\Links\GPUTools cannot be uninstalled because it does not reside in the standard paclet repository.

PacletUninstall::nodelete: The paclet named OpenCLLink at location E:\Mathematica 12.1\SystemFiles\Links\OpenCLLink cannot be uninstalled because it does not reside in the standard paclet repository.

General::stop: Further output of PacletUninstall::nodelete will be suppressed during this calculation.
```